# Pandas get date value by index

Tags: python, pandas

df_transactions is a dataframe that looks like this:

```
   id  date        is_cancel
0   A   2017-10-30     0
1   A   2017-10-31     1
2   B   2017-09-14     0
3   B   2017-09-15     0
```

I did

```
mask = df_transactions.groupby('id',as_index=False)['is_cancel'].nth(-1)==1
```

to get the boolean value of id's with is_cancel==1 on their last row.
I would like to get '2017-10-31' but

```
replacement = df_transactions.loc[mask[mask].index]['date']
```

returns

```
1   2017-10-31
```

I tried .values but I get

```
['2017-10-31T00:00:00.000000000']
```

Any ways to get just the date? The date column is a numpy.datetime64 type

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There is possible `mask` return more `True`s, so need select value by position - e.g. first value by `[0]`:

```
print (df_transactions)
  id        date  is_cancel
0  A  2017-10-30          0
1  A  2017-10-31          1
2  B  2017-09-14          0
3  B  2017-09-15          1
4  C  2017-09-18          0
5  C  2017-09-19          0


mask = df_transactions.groupby('id',as_index=False)['is_cancel'].nth(-1)==1
print (mask)
1     True
3     True
5    False
Name: is_cancel, dtype: bool

replacement = df_transactions.loc[mask[mask].index, 'date']
print (replacement)
1    2017-10-31
3    2017-09-15
Name: date, dtype: object

print (replacement.iat[0])
2017-10-31 00:00:00

print (replacement.values[0])
2017-10-31T00:00:00.000000000
```

---

```
#for date
print (replacement.iat[0].date())
2017-10-31

print (type(replacement.iat[0].date()))
<class 'datetime.date'>

#for string
print (replacement.iat[0].strftime('%Y-%m-%d'))
2017-10-31

print (type(replacement.iat[0].strftime('%Y-%m-%d')))
<class 'str'>
```

Comment: tried replacement = df_transactions.loc[mask[mask].index, 'date'].item(), it returns a long type integer like this 1483833600000000000

Comment: OK, then use `replacement = df_transactions.loc[mask[mask].index, 'date'].iat[0]`, maybe use some old version of pandas

Comment: it returned 2017-10-31 00:00:00 of type <class 'pandas._libs.tslib.Timestamp'> I'm using pandas version 0.20.3

Comment: OK, I think it is correct output, because all pandas dates are datetimes (`Timestamp`)

Comment: But if need date - `print (replacement.iat[0].date())`

Comment: facing a big problem now because my df_transactions has 20 million rows. any idea how to do this? for loop isn't helping

Comment: if `mask = df_transactions.groupby('id',as_index=False)['is_cancel'].nth(-1)==1` is slow, it it problem, because it is native pandas function. Maybe problem is to big dataframe :( Then need a lot of RAM, but if much data python is slow... :(

Comment: done ! thank you. I actually tried for looping the is_cancel==1 (which as 400k rows) and its still running now it has been 3 hrs.